# How to pass value from session variable to view in foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables

I have following code:

```
$m1 =  $this->dbop->customquery('SELECT DISTINCT number FROM users');
    $message =''; $email='';            

    $count=array();
    foreach($m1 as $item){
            $message='';
     $count=array();
        $m2 =  $this->dbop->customquery("SELECT *  FROM users where 
       number='".$item->number."'");
        foreach ($m2 as $value) {
            //$data['alldata'] = $value;
         $count[] =  $this->dbop->customquery("SELECT *  FROM 
     s_data where userid='".$value->id."'");
         $os_count =  $this->dbop->customquery("SELECT *  FROM 
       os where userid='".$value->id."'");
        $data['dd']=$this->dbop->customquery("SELECT *  FROM os 
      where userid='".$value->id."'");
        }


    }

    $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $this->load->view('header-inside', $data);      
    $this->load->view('am-report' , $data);
    $this->load->view('crm/footer-inside');
```

I want to pass the `$data['dd]` to view.
What currently I am receving is only first value.
Help me for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing $data['dd'] value. every time foreach loop runs it will replace with new value. Instead do like this

```
$data['dd'][] = $this->dbop->customquery("SELECT *  FROM os 
  where userid='".$value->id."'");
```

Comment: i had done the  way use said but now its now showing anything in view @AnilShrestha

Comment: what does anything mean. you should use foreach to echo its values since it is an array

Comment: opps there was my mistakes. You method works out..Thanks